# nest api - cryptic error message when creating client with product data write permissions

Tags: nest-api

I'm attempting to create a google nest client to write electricity monitor data to the Nest for display in the energy history plot, but although I'm able to create a test client with thermostat read permissions, when I attempt to create a new client with product data write permissions I get an error message saying "scopes.justification exceeds required maximum length of 140".  I don't see any fields with more than 140 characters and an email to the Nest team has been unanswered for several days.

I should say I'm leaving the OAuth redirect field blank because I'm still trying to learn exactly how OAuth is meant to work and if the redirect is a site I need to write and host or what, but it appears to be optional and one can edit client details later or use a PIN so doesn't seem that's the issue, but I could be wrong.

Anyone had this issue or able to provide some tips?

Comment: I should add that I realize this question and format might not be completely within the scope of stack overflow, but the Nest developer page routes here.  Please advise/comment if there's a better or more appropriate way to word this.

Comment: When you add the product data write permissions, the flow ends with "Our developer relations team will contact you in the next few days to confirm your information and configure your data paths." Did you get a confirmation? The developer documentation only intends to point here for unanswered programming questions, not "I haven't received a response yet".

Comment: No, I don't get that far, the error appears at the top of the page where new client information is first entered.  I don't ever get the message you describe stating the developer team will contact me.